# ios sqlite error : attempt to write a read-only database

Tags: ios, sqlite, unity-game-engine

I made the iOS app unity.

It also successfully selected data from sqlite.

But when I insert, the error below appears.

`mono.data.sqlite.sqliteexception (0x80004005): attempt to write a read-only database`

The path to the DB file is here.

```
string filepath = Application.dataPath + "/Raw/Data.db";
if (!File.Exists(filepath))
{
    File.Copy(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Raw/Data.db", filepath);
}
```

I wonder if I should set write permissions or change the path of the file.

What should I do if I have to grant write permission?

If I have to change the route, where should I go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the official documentation you have this:

[On many platforms, the streaming assets folder location is read-only; you can not modify or write new files there at runtime. Use Application.persistentDataPath for a folder location that is writable.](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html)

Solution: Use Application.persistentDataPath instead of streaming asset folder.

Comment: It was a simple and accurate explanation.